# Selenide не находит элемент после действия над ним (setValue)

Tags: java, selenide

Определил элемент поле ввода:

```
public SelenideElement inputVatNumber = $(xpath("//*[@data-ui-test='input-vatNumber']"));
```

Записал в него строку:

```
$(inputVatNumber).setValue("Строка");
```

Убрал с поля ввода фокус.
Хочу изменить введенную строку:

```
$(inputVatNumber).setValue("изменить строку");
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Element should be visible or transparent: visible or have css value opacity=0 {StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document}
Element: 'StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document'
Actual value: StaleElementReferenceException: stale element refe

Caused by: StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы два раза заворачиваете в доллар? Это лишнее.
Поменяйте `$(inputVatNumber).setValue(...)` на `inputVatNumber.setValue("...")`

Comment: Не помогает. Если я ввел в поле ввода строку, потом убрал с него фокус, то второй раз поле ввода не находит. Выдает вышеуказанную ошибку

Comment: Понял проблему, она была не в тесте. Андрей, спасибо за уделенное время!